# Conditional Averages in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have dataset- 5000 dates since 1995 and the price of a good on each date. I want to calculate an annual average for these. I basically want to tell excel to average all of the cells for the year xxxx, average all of the cells with the year xxxy, etc. I have been playing around with if( , left(, average(, in a new table with all the years I want to find averages for. I'm not an expert at excel. This is what the dataset looks like now. I'd love to know how to do this since I need to do this kind of thing all the time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnTmH.png)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If an answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ to the left of the text, which means "yes, this is THE answer"!

Answer (score 0):

Use a "3D-formula"...
`=SUM(IF(YEAR(A:A)=$D$1,B:B,0))/SUM(IF(YEAR(A:A)=$D$1,1,0))`

Type it in and then hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  (works in both Excel and LibreOffice Calc)

The formula gets `{...}` curly braces at the ends if you do it correctly.

Now, enter the year to average in D1

How:
`A:A` and `B:B` takes the values in the entire column, change to a more limited range if that is what you have.

As these are ranges of cells, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is required, making the formula loop through all the cells in the range.
As the year value in D1 should be used for all comparisons, it needs the `$`'s.

The first `IF(...)` picks out the relevant rows, and returns the corresponding values in the B column, which then are fed to `SUM()`.

Likewise the second `IF(...)` selects the same rows again, but returns a `1` for each one, making up the COUNT of rows as `SUM(...)` has done it's job.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple with an `AVEAGEIFS` function deployed like this:

List all your years in D2 down and then in E2 use this formula

`=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(D2,1,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(D2+1,1,1))`

copy the formula down for all years